# Display hovertool for the uppermost glyph in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a graph with several hundreds of glyphs on it, generated in bokeh. All the glyphs have a hovertool associated with them that shows a popup window with an image in it when moused over.

Some of the glyphs have 4-5 glyphs layered underneath them, and when someone mouses over them, all the hovertools are displayed.

Is it possible to only display the hovertool for the uppermost glyph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh 1.3.4 there is no way to control the number of tooltips displayed without creating some sort of a custom extension. There is an open issue [`#9087` Provide max_tooltips property on HoverTool](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9087) that is targeted for one of the next few releases.

But note: that work will just take *a* tooltip out of multiple to show. The draw order for a single glyph is not well-defined, it can change due to: spatial indexing, selections, "Level of Detail" mode being active, and other things. I don't know that there will ever be a reliable notion of "total z-order" such that e.g the "top" circle could be the one picked (and always be the same index). A more sophisticated selection manager could sort or condition on other CDS column values, etc. though, so you could potentially explicitly provide the order you intend.